# Checking a large list of permutations. Any advice to get it to run faster?

Tags: python, optimization, bigdata, permutation

I have about 95,000,000 permutations to check.
I have 8 lists of varying length, each string identifies properties (a-k) defined in an excel sheet.
e.g

```
bcdgj
```

has properties b, c, d, g and j

I need to find just one permutation that contains at least 3 of every property and then match those properties to the data in the spreadsheet

I have made this script (my first attempt at using python)

```py
import numpy
import itertools

for x in itertools.product(['abfhj','bcdgj','fghij','abcj','bdgk','abgi','cdei','cdgi','dgik','aghi','abgh','bfhk'],['cdei','bcdgj','abcgi','abcj','abfj','bdfj','cdgi','bhjk','bdgk','dgik'],['afhk','cdgik','cegik','bdgi','cgij','cdei','bcgi','abgh'],['fhjk','bdgij','cgij','abk','ajk','bdk','cik','cdk','cei','fgj'],['abe','abcf','afh','cdi','afj','cdg','abi','cei','cgk','ceg','cgi'],['cdgi','bcgj','bcgi','bcdg','abfh','bdhi','bdgi','bdk','fhk','bei','beg','fgi','abf','abc','egi'],['bcdgik','cegik','chik','afhj','abcj','abfj'],['ceg','bcfg','cgi','bdg','afj','cgj','fhk','cfk','dgk','bcj']):
    gear = ''.join(x)
    count_a = gear.count('a')
    count_b = gear.count('b')
    count_c = gear.count('c')
    count_d = gear.count('d')
    count_e = gear.count('e')
    count_f = gear.count('f')
    count_g = gear.count('g')
    count_h = gear.count('h')
    count_i = gear.count('i')
    count_j = gear.count('j')
    count_k = gear.count('k')
    score_a = numpy.clip(count_a, 0, 3)
    score_b = numpy.clip(count_b, 0, 3)
    score_c = numpy.clip(count_c, 0, 3)
    score_d = numpy.clip(count_d, 0, 3)
    score_e = numpy.clip(count_e, 0, 3)
    score_f = numpy.clip(count_f, 0, 3)
    score_g = numpy.clip(count_g, 0, 3)
    score_h = numpy.clip(count_h, 0, 3)
    score_i = numpy.clip(count_i, 0, 3)
    score_j = numpy.clip(count_j, 0, 3)
    score_k = numpy.clip(count_k, 0, 3)
    rating = score_a + score_b + score_c + score_d + score_e + score_f + score_g + score_h + score_i + score_j + score_k
    if rating == 33:
        print(x)
        print(rating)
```

I've adjusted the rating requirement to test that it's working, it is but it's going to take a while to crunch through 95,000,000 permutations. Anyone have any advice for getting it to run faster?
I think I've already reduced the number of values in each list as much as I can, the excel sheet the data comes from has several hundred entries per list and I've managed to reduce it to 6-12 per list.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem. One char (letter) is a property or string is property? Could you give example of what is "good" permutation and what is "bad" permutation, and why?

Comment: One character is a property, the string identifies which properties are present.

Comment: A good permutation is one where every property (character) appears at least 3 times. With the excel data there is a threshold of 3 for any property (easily done) which allows access to data related to that property. I'm trying to find out if there is single combination that that will work for every property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from itertools import groupby, product

data = (
    ['abfhj','bcdgj','fghij','abcj','bdgk','abgi','cdei','cdgi','dgik','aghi','abgh','bfhk'],
    ['cdei','bcdgj','abcgi','abcj','abfj','bdfj','cdgi','bhjk','bdgk','dgik'],
    ['afhk','cdgik','cegik','bdgi','cgij','cdei','bcgi','abgh'],
    ['fhjk','bdgij','cgij','abk','ajk','bdk','cik','cdk','cei','fgj'],
    ['abe','abcf','afh','cdi','afj','cdg','abi','cei','cgk','ceg','cgi'],
    ['cdgi','bcgj','bcgi','bcdg','abfh','bdhi','bdgi','bdk','fhk','bei','beg','fgi','abf','abc ','egi'],
    ['bcdgik','cegik','chik','afhj','abcj','abfj'],
    ['ceg','bcfg','cgi','bdg','afj','cgj','fhk','cfk','dgk','bcj'],
)

REQ_PROPS = set("abcdefghijk")

for x in product(*data):
    permu = ''.join(x)
    # if the permutation does not contain all letters from a-k, skip it.
    if REQ_PROPS.difference(permu):
        continue

    prop_map = dict.fromkeys(permu)
    for prop, group in groupby(sorted(permu)):
        group_rating = len(tuple(group))
        # dont bother searching more props of this permutation if the current
        # property has a rating less than 3
        if group_rating < 3:
            break
        prop_map[prop] = group_rating
    # check if this permutation satisfies the requirement and exit if it does.
    if all(v is not None for v in prop_map.values()):
        print(x)
        print(prop_map)  # total rating of each property
        break
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but the most obvious optimization would be to "short-circuit" the search by stopping as soon as a permutation does not have all required properties or when a permutation's property fails to have at least 3 instances. This is achieved by first sorting the permutation and then grouping it by property. After grouping you check if each property's frequency is not less than 3. If the check does not fail for all properties then you have your answer, else move on to the next permutation.

I ran the program using the example data provided it appears that there is no solution that contains all `a-k` properties. Maybe you need a bigger dataset.

Comment: That's definitely looks better than my code. Is there a way to check that all the properties are present though? The answer you have there doesn't work, k has a value of 0. I tried your code without the break so it'd keep running there were a lot of solutions with missing properties.

Comment: "I need to find just one permutation that contains at least 3 of every property" <- I took that as meaning every property contained in a given permutation. Your description is not very obvious so I was not sure if this is what you wanted. You can ensure that the returned solution contains all a-k properties by testing the set of letter right after making the string. I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I ran the updated program using the example data provided it appears that there is no solution that contains all `a-k` properties. Maybe you need a bigger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

**Python is not designed to write computationally-intensive pure-Python codes**. It is meant to be used as glue code. The intensive part should be vectorized, that is, optimized in compiled native languages like C. This is especially true with the default implementation of CPython which is an *interpreter*. Any call to a function is pretty expensive (100 ns per `gear.count`).

Still, there are many sources of slowdown that can be avoided. First of all, strings are unicode-based ones and **unicode strings are slow** to compute (because of the non trivial encoding and the variable size). Your code create a new string object in every iteration of the loop. **Creating new objects is expensive**. The thing is Python strings are immutable so there is no way not to create new string except not using strings at all. Additionally, the same thing is true for Numpy operations: Numpy is not designed to compute very small array so it introduce a significant overhead. The string is rebuilt from scratch with `''.join(...)` but only the last part needs to be modified. The same thing is true for counting characters: you can only recompute the part that is changing from one iteration to another. Moreover, there is no need for `numpy.clip` since the number of item cannot be negative: you can replace this with a call to `score_xxx = min(count_xxx, 3)`. Note that this operation can be executed in parallel (using multiprocessing in pure-Python). That being said, rewriting this in C should be many order of magnitude faster if one pay attention to the aforementioned points.

If you are bound to Python, you can use **just-in-time compilers like Numba** to do that. However, Numba do not support well strings. This is not much a problem since we should not use it for sake of performance here anyway. The strings can be translated to ASCII-based integer arrays and the itertool generator can be replaced with basic loops.

One way to do it efficiently in Numba is to 1. split the Cartesian product in two parts and compute two quite big arrays with the counts (using basic loops), 2. then compute the Cartesian product of the two groups (using a 2 nested loops).